# How to change a NETWORK drive letter in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, filesystems, path, drive-letter, network-drive

### BACKGROUND

I have assigned a network drive to volume `\\Raid` as `H:` to "fool" Lightroom that it is a "normal" drive.

This has been working perfect util Vista suddenly decided to automatically reinstall all USB units, hence changing the drive letter for my network path from `H:` to `M:`

Since all photos in Lightroom are tied to the drive letter it can't find any of my photos and reassign them will take to much time.

### PROBLEM

I went to the Computer Management to reassign the drive letter but it only lists "physical" drives, no network path.

Right click->Property page on the drive doesn't give me the tool to rename the drive letter either.

### QUESTION

How can I force (and guarantee) that my network drive always is the same (in the same way you can set the drive letter for a "normal" drive (USB/ATA/IDE etc...)

// Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Open a cmd and use:

NET USE M: /D

NET USE H: \machine\sharename /PERSISTENT:YES

Comment: I'm not at the machine right now, but I suppose that /PERSISTENT:YES means that I don't need to do this on every boot ;) I need to login with a different account as well, how do I supply a login name and password?

Comment: Yes it means exactly that :-) ... for different credentials you can use NET USE H: \\foo\foo /PERSISTENT:YES /USER:domain\username password. Also NET USE /? will show you a short guide

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and vote when I get the chance...

Comment: I'm not entirely certain but I think that this will still have a problem when Windows decides it wants that drive letter for a physical device. This is especially true if the device was plugged in and then the system rebooted since the physical device will come active before the network. You should always allocate network resources from the other end of the alphabet to avoid this problem. That is why, on corporate systems, the network drives are typically x:, y: and z:

Comment: I use the opposite way: USB devices are dynamically allocated from Z: going up, and network resources are from N: going down. I like that no matter what happens in the system, the first usb drive I connect goes straight to Z: